# Can you auto-push to a subtree (GitLab-CI) with a Merge to Upstream as trigger?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, git-subtree, subtree

This is a really high level question as we are in a brainstorming session currently. On that note, I am not a GitLab expert on any level.

That said.

In GitLab we are trying to establish a new process flow for a large shared services group. Currently we have 1 giant project that needs to broken out into 2 (a main project and a smaller coorelated project). My preference is to be able to do the following.

1. Developer submits merge request to upstream project - A
2. Merge Request accepted and successfully merged to upstream project - A
3. In upstream project - A - IF detection of changes to files within sub-folders starting with CD* is detected THEN autopush and merge to upstream project - B - only the changes within CD*

Is this doable? Do we have to make B a sub-tree of A in order for it to work?

OPEN TO ANY IDEAS! Thanks!

Nothing! we are brainstorming still before even going down this path.

Comment: sorry everyone, didnt realize my line breaks were going to disappear in this post. in the 3rd paragraph there are 3 steps, each numbered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [only changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) in your YAML file to specify that a job should only trigger on changes to specific files or directories combined with using [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger-premium) to specify the upstream project that should trigger (note trigger is a paid feature though).